# Problems with reading a .txt file

Tags: c++

I am looking for an answer to my question, but i didn't find it in any other place.

I'm trying to read from a .txt file, that is located in the same directory as my project files.

I wrote this simple code:

```
ifstream file("file.txt");
std::string line;
std::getline(file, line);
cout << line;
```

...but unfortunately, nothing happened, not even an error or crashing.

Upon exploring a little further... even if I change the name of the txt("file") file, to the name of a file that doesn't exist, nothing happens.

What am I missing?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

if your error is due to opening file then `provide full path to the file` and check.

in your code you are reading the first line so if it is a white space then you can see nothing as output.

you must to iterate over each line until the last line (reaching the end of file EOF).

```
// let's say your file is "test.txt" which is located in D\\MyDB
// ifstream file("file.txt");

ifstream file("D:\\MyDB\\test.txt"); // use full path instead and check manully whether the file is there or not
std::string line;

if(file.fail())
    cout << "Opening file failed!" << endl;
else  
    while(std::getline(file, line))
    {
        cout << line;
    }
```

if it works when providing the full path then your current path is not the same as your project.

you can change the current directory using some API so if you are on windows then use: `SetCurrentDirectory(path);` and on linux use: `chdir(sDirectory.c_str());`

** I mean compilers not OS

Comment: still doesnt successful, i wrote this line now : cout << "error opening file: " << strerror(errno);   and i got : "No such file or directory" , what do i miss?

Comment: @Realto where is your file add the full path please.

Comment: /Users/John/ClionProjects/MyProject

Comment: did you try this: `ifstream file("/Users/John/ClionProjects/MyProject/file.txt")`?

Comment: ok! something is getting on the right ! as you ask me for the full path i wrote at in ifstream file(" /Users/John/ClionProjects/MyProject/file.txt"); and now its reading from my file , how can i do that it will recognize that the file in the project directory?

Comment: you can use an API to change your current directory so on windows

Comment: [std::basic_ios::fail](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) doesn't do what you think it does. Plus, the current working directory is a per-process setting. Any thread can change it at any time. Don't ever rely on it having any particular value.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know there were no errors? You did not check.

```
#include <cerrno>
```

and then

```
ifstream file("file.txt");
if (file) // is the file readable?
{
    std::string line;
    if (std::getline(file, line)) // did we manage to read anything?
    {
        cout << line;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File IO error";
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "error opening file: " << strerror(errno);
}
```

performs rudimentary checking.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer.to be more clear , the program run without crashing , but when i run your code i got "error opening file". so how can i know what im doing wrong?

Comment: @Realto Added some code to print out *why* the file failed to open.

Comment: ok , so i got this error: "No such file or directory", buy why ? i put the file in the directory that include all the project files, do i miss something ?

Comment: @Realto You have fallen victim to the Working Directory. A program can be run from anywhere and the first place it looks for a file without an absolute path is the directory from which it was run.  A debugger often runs the program from some folder set in the project properties, and this may not be where you think it is. [Use the `getcwd` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getcwd.html) to find out where the working directory is.